# Do words that have liaison before a vowel have no audible release before a consonant?

Tags: phonétique, liaisons

In the word "les", although the final "s" is not sounded when followed by a consonant, is it still shaped in the mouth? I am wondering why the letter becomes audible before a vowel.

> les livres /le livr/

*le<s>s</s> livres* ("s" in "les" is silent)

> les autres /le zotr/

*le<s>s</s>z-autres* ("s" in "les" is pronounced as "z")

I understand how to apply the rule for liaison but I was wondering if there is a phonological explanation for it. I want to know the same thing for all letters that are usually not sounded except when the next word starts with a vowel. I have a text book which states that liaison also occurs after numbers:

> *cinq livres* /sõ livr/

*cin<s>q</s> livres* ("q" in "cinq" is silent)

> cinq autres /sõ kotr/

*cin<s>q</s>k-autres* ("q" in "cinq" is pronounced as "k")

So again, in this example, is the "k" shaped by the mouth but not sounded when followed by a consonant?

Apologies for any spelling or pronunciation mistakes.

### EDIT

There seems to be too much focus on the word *cinq*. I was just looking for an example that ended in a letter other than *s*. I want to know about the phenomenon as a whole, not focus on specific examples, whether they are right or wrong. Also, I can only understand French if it is very, very simple. Respondez en anglais, s'il vous plait! Respond in English please!

Comment: Le `q` de cinq se prononce dans *cinq livres*

Comment: ou pas, les deux s'entendent.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm used to it but I actually find it more difficult to pronounce it without the liaison than with it... maybe that's why ?

Comment: There is more at play than the rule about _liaison_, and using that rule as an angle for a number shadows other rules/exceptions about the _déterminant numéral_ i.e. _Grevisse_ (591, c-). _Trésor_ has insightful [material](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cinq); see also [this](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3135). It is not easy to present this clearly and concisely; maybe someone knows how.

Comment: How I wish I could understand the French comments.

Comment: @cl-r *Not pronouncing the last *q* in *cinq* is not that much a regional trait but more an age and/or an education one. For example when *livre* is used as a weight unit, *cinq livres de beurre* is often pronounced like *une pièce de cinq francs* was, without a /k/.

Comment: The French comments say, "The 'q' in 'cinq' *is* pronounced (not silent)"; and the reply is, "Or not (that 'q' isn't pronounced): either/both (pronounced and/or not pronounced) are heard in practice".

Comment: @ChrisW the *q* is not silent when *livre* == *book*. It can be omitted (familiar or regionalism) when *livre* == *pound*, or when replacing *cin[q]* by *saint* or by *sein* has no signification.

Answer (score 6):

As you wrote later in your question, the *cinq* example is indeed a poor choice.

The reason is it is not pertaining to the list of words subject to *liaison*. A *liaison* happen when a word has an ending consonant only pronounced when the word is followed by a vowel or a mute h but not in other cases, like for example when the word is alone or the last one of a sentence.

On the opposite, *cinq* has its last consonant pronounced in that latter case and can actually always be pronounced. Sometimes, its last [k] is not pronounced when the following word starts with a consonant. This is an *elision* case, not a *liaison* one.

Back to your title question, no, words that are subject to *liaison* never have their last consonant causing an audible effect before a word starting with another consonant. These words are always pronounced just like if this letter does not exist at all. Doing otherwise it is a typical non native speaker mistake, like "*Un petit garçon*" pronounced like "*Un petite garçon*".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include the letter 'q' when your are pronouncing *cinq livres*, French people can hear *saint*, like *holy book*.

When *livre = book*, the usual pronunciation always includes a brief 'q' even in front of a consonant to discriminate signification.

Comment: Et puis entre « les cinq libérés », « les seins libérés » et « les saints libérés », est-ce qu’il y a moyen/besoin de faire une distinction phonétique ?

Comment: @PapaPoule Pour *cinq* il n'y a pas de problème puisqu'il a un *q* audible, mais l'homophonie *sein/saint* est la source de moult autres jeux de mots.

Comment: @cl-r, you seem to be a native French speaker and I appreciate your attention to my question! Let's focus on _les_, though. If I pronounce _les autres_ as two separate words, my tongue touches the roof of my mouth for the _l_, then leaves it for the _e(s)_. If I use liaison my tongue touches the roof of my mouth again in a slightly different way before I start saying _autres_. In _les livres_ for modern French speakers does the tongue touch the roof of the mouth for the _s_ in _les_ without being sounded? Maybe another word would be better as the _l_ in _livre_ could complicate things.

Comment: @CJDennis  *l* need the end of the tongue to be like vertical, for liaison pronounced *z* les [z]autres, tongue is near the teeth  because the written *s* ofe *les* is sounded *z*. In *les livres* You have two *l*, and the *s* is muted -- As you have unsderstood reading my responses, I'm a pure francophone figthing with english :)

Comment: @cl-r Your English is much better than my French! I've obviously used terrible examples. In English although the final letter is usually lightly sounded it is possible to omit it and still be understood. E.g. _I have a cat_, _I have a cap_. I can omit the final _t_ and _p_ in each sentence but as long as my mouth still forms the sounds one sentence can be distinguished from the other. For the first my tongue touches the roof of my mouth after /kæ/ and for the second my lips press together after /kæ/. How about in _les poissons_? Even though the first _s_ is silent is it shaped in the mouth?

Comment: For future readers: What @CJDennis is referring to is called an "unreleased consonant", and it simply a feature of English. Compare: "great beard" / "grey beard". They are distinguished by a faint, unreleased 't'. French does not have this phenomenon. The 's' in 'les' is truly silent in his example of 'les livres'.

"How about in les poissons?" -> Nope, the 's' is totally and completely unarticulated in any way shape or form. It's a silent letter in the usual sense of the word. English examples: 'gh' in 'eight', 'h' in 'hour', 'k' in 'knife', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. If I understand well, you want to know which silent letters do which sound.
Let me first first recall you that there is three types of "liaisons" in french: the necessary ones, the optional ones and the forbidden ones. I'm saying that, because the liaisons that I'm presenting are sometimes optional.
There is in french 6 liaisons' sounds.

- /z/, which is done with a final "s", "z" or "x".
- /t/, which is done with a final "t" or "d"
- /n/, which is done with a final "n"
- /p/ (always optional) which is done with a final "p"
- /r/ ( always optional) which is done with a final "r"
- /k/ (always optional) which is done with a final "c" or "g"

Several remarks:

- the three last liaisons are really rare.
- the "r"-liaisons is said to be necessary with the adjectives "premier" and "dernier" by the Académie français. I'm not here to say what I think about the Académie française, but you have to know that what they say is always interessing, but often not representative to what the french speakers say and write.
- For the number between 1 and 10, it's really some crap. Here is the list explaining for each of them:
- un (liaison in /n/)
- deux (liaison in /z/)
- trois (liaison in /z/)
- quatre (nothing)
- cinq (crap! It depends on regions. In some regions, the "q" is always pronounced. In the other, like mine, it is only pronouced if the next word begins with a vowel (like a liaison) but also if it is followed by a break (point or comma).
- six (crap! Almost like cinq. It is pronouced /z/ before a vowel-begining word and !!! /s/ before a break. )
- sept (the "t" is always pronounced)
- huit (crap! exactly like cinq, but with the sound /t/ instead of /k/)
- neuf (crap! Almost like six. It is pronouced /v/ before a vowel-begining word and !!! /f/ before a break. )
- dix (crap! Exactly like six)

I hope I have answered your question. There is still a lot of things to say about the liaisons. So feel free to ask if you have other questions :)

By the way if there is an answer satisfying you, please mark it in order to show that the topic was ... answered!

Comment: My question is about a particular phenomenon found in some languages like Vietnamese. For example, "cat" would be pronounced "ka(t)", not "ka". You can't hear the "t", but you can hear they were just about to say it, then stopped.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, Let's not focus on this "cinq". What you are talking about is `liaison`

If I'm not mistaken, the "liaison" only occurs with plural. 
`les enfants`, `les avions`... 
The following word begins with a voyel.

There is no liaison with proper nouns
`Paris a de grandes rues` (don't pronounce the 's')

There are some exceptions.

`Les haricots` (beans). As "haricots" begins with a consonant, there is no liaison. Same for "handicapés".

But, I have always heard `les hopitaux` with the liaison.

Also, to complete the answer, Jilliagre is right, there is no "liaison" with words ending by a consonant.

Comment: Liaisons have nothing to do with being plural: un-n-enfant, des-z-enfants. There can be liaisons with proper nouns, the absence of a liaison in “Paris a de grandes rues” is due to there being no liaison between the subject and the verb. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)) for more details. With *haricots*, *hôpitaux*, etc. the issue is whether the H is “*muet*” (doesn't count) or “*aspiré*” (counts as a consonant which isn't sounded but prevents a liaison). Again, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_h).

Comment: Yes, thinking of it `Paris et son-n-environnement`. "Son" isn't plural. What is the rule for "Paris" ? You say `Les bons-z-et les méchants` but not `Paris-z-et ...` Nothing to do with the fact that it's a proper noun ?